# How to rename string duplicates in python?

Tags: python, duplicates, rename

I am trying to replace duplicate string with duplicate integer.
For example:

```
mylist = ["name", "state", "name", "city", "city", "name", "zip", "zip", "name"]
```

I want the list as

```
mylist = [1, 'State', 1, 2,2,1,3,3,1]
```

All name renamed as 1, city as 2 and zip 3. If there are more duplicates those will be also renamed as 4, 5 6 etc.

I have tried with

```
mylist = ["name", "state", "name", "city", "name", "zip", "zip"]
from collections import Counter 
counts = Counter(mylist) 
for s,num in counts.items():
    if num > 1:
       mylist[mylist.index(s)] = 1
```

But got

```
mylist = [1, 'state', 'name', 'city', 'name', 1, 'zip']
```

How to get 1 for name, 2 for city, 3 for zip and 4 for next duplicate value?

Comment: `index` returns index of only first occurance of element in list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just modified your code

```
mylist = ["name", "state", "name", "city", "city", "name", "zip", "zip", "name"]
from collections import Counter
counts = Counter(mylist)
counts
Out[309]: Counter({'city': 1, 'name': 3, 'state': 1, 'zip': 2})
Count=1
for s,num in counts.items():
    if num > 1:
       for  i, j in enumerate(mylist):
           if j==s:
               mylist[i] = Count
       Count=Count+1
mylist
Out[320]: [1, 'state', 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1]
```

Comment: if I want to put numbers for unique values too what should I do? Is it possible that code will return 1 for name(duplicate value), 2 for (unique value) then 3 for next duplicate value and 4,5,6 for next unique or duplicate values. Your answered my question already and code is working fine. Can I do that in one function instead of writing another function for unique values. Thanks

Comment: num >= 1 did the desired job.

Answer (score 1):

Almost there! I commented the additional code:

```
from collections import Counter 

mylist = ["name", "state", "name", "city", "city", "name", "zip", "zip", "name"]

counts = Counter(mylist) 

c = 0

for s,num in counts.items():
    if num > 1:
      c+= 1 # create a variable (integer) to replace the var in the list (starting with 1 as in your example)
      for x in mylist: # since index returns only the first instance, iterate over your list
        if x == s: 
          mylist[mylist.index(x)] = c # replace with your new integer variable

print(mylist)
# [1, 'state', 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Construct a dictionary of indices for each item in `mylist` - this is similar to using collections.Counter except it preserves the item indices. Use an OrderedDict to preserve the order of the items in the list.

```
import collections
mylist = ["name", "state", "name", "city", "city", "name", "zip", "zip", "name"]       
d = collections.OrderedDict()
for index, item in enumerate(mylist):
    try:
        d[item].append(index)
    except KeyError:
        d[item] = [index]
```

Iterate over the dictionary values; check the length; change the item if the criteria is met.

```
count = 1
for indices in d.values():
    if len(indices) > 1:
        for index in indices:
            mylist[index] = count
        count+=1
print(mylist)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the most beautiful solution, but this works:

```
mylist = ["name", "state", "name", "city", "city", "name", "zip", "zip"]
from collections import Counter 
counts = Counter(mylist) 
val = 1
for s,num in counts.items():
    if num > 1:
        counts[s] = val
        val += 1
    else:
        counts[s] = 0
mylist = [x if counts[x]==0 else counts[x] for x in mylist]
mylist
```

You get then [1, 'state', 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3]

Comment: Use the original list otherwise it looks like you have a bug.

Answer (score 0):

You're very close...

```
for s in counts:
    if counts[s] > 1: 
        mylist[mylist.index(s)] = mylist.index(s)
# myList is now [0, 'state', 2, 'city', 'name', 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this solution:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import count
from operator import itemgetter

mylist = ["name", "state", "name", "city", "city", "name", "zip", "zip", "name"]
C = Counter(mylist)
c = count(start=1)
C = {k: next(c) if v > 1 else k for k, v in C.items()}
itemgetter(*mylist)(C)
# (1, 'state', 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1)
```